# REPLACE not finding all occurrences

Tags: sql-server, string

Came across this unexpected behaviour while writing code to parse ;-delimited lists in an SQL column.

What I'm doing at this point is replacing only occurrences which are surrounded by delimiters, to avoid false positives.  Without the delimiters, replacing "Alice" in "Alice;Bob;Alice;Alice in Wonderland;Charlie" would produce "Bob;in Wonderland;Charlie".

Code to reproduce:

```
SELECT REPLACE('Alice;Alice;Alice;Alice;Alice;Alice',';Alice;',';Bob;')
```

This is 6 repetitions of Alice, with 4 surrounded by delimiters.  Expected result:

```
Alice;Bob;Bob;Bob;Bob;Alice
```

Actual result:

```
Alice;Bob;Alice;Bob;Alice;Alice
```

Why have the 3rd and 5th Alices not been replaced?

My theory is that when REPLACE finds ";Alice;" in the second position, it "reserves" that block of text, so that the following, 3rd ";Alice;", which overlaps with the 2nd by one character, is unavailable to REPLACE as a match.  Logically enough, because the REPLACEment of the first found occurrence might replace it with anything at all; for example, if it replaced it with "#Alice#" then the 3rd ";Alice;" would now be "#Alice;" - no match.

In this instance the REPLACE doesn't actually change the ";" shared by the 2nd and 3rd instances: but internally the REPLACE function is cautious and simply moves on past the last character of the 2nd Alice.  And the same happens with the 4th and 5th occurrences.

Workaround is to wrap the REPLACE in a WHILE, until the search string is no longer found.

Does anyone have a better explanation or workaround?

Comment: It doesn't reserve anything. It's just that the text of the replacement is not considered when it looks for the next match. It doesn't look for another match from the start of the string each time, it proceeds from the next character after the end of the previous replacement. It would be easy to create infinite replacement loops otherwise.

Comment: It's working as expected. `REPLACE` doesn't replace the same character twice. Otherwise something `REPLACE('ABC','C','CD')` would loop infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked a workaround, i'd temporarily replace the delimiter with a double colon:

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE('Alice;Alice;Alice;Alice;Alice;Alice',';',';;')  -- First, make your delimiter a double colon so it can be independently consumed
        ,';Alice;',';Bob;'                                      -- Then, search as your initial idea
    )
,';;',';'                                                       -- Finally, revert to single-length delimiters
)
```

Result:

> Alice;Bob;Bob;Bob;Bob;Alice

Answer (score 0):

Here's a visual representation of the two matches of `;Alice;` that will be replaced by `;Bob;`:

[image]